# How to have multiple CURLOPT_USERAGENT in one query?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have the following code which currently use only one user agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8`.

My question is how I can use multiple user agents in one time? It should change user agent if the current one will not pass.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8');
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to make multiple requests with different user agents, yes? What have you tried so far to do that? Also, what is your use case for that?  (Wondering because it sounds a bit like you are trying to sneak in somewhere)

Comment: You can't do that. One request, one user agent. Just like a browser. You would need to evaluate the response and try a different user agent if the last one didn't pass.